# Javascript error on google maps main.js

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
TypeError: a is null
https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/15a/main.js
Line 43
```

This is what I'm getting. I'm using Firefox 33.1, Windows 7, and this is the script tag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Nothing fancy. Did Google not test this script, or...? How do we get Google to solve this problem?

The same error happens when I tell the script tag to give me API version 3.17 or 3.16. I verified that version selection works, so this error has been around for a while now.

Comment: I believe you should provide a jsFiddle with the error. I've tried including the library with your snippet and it works, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: The problem is most likely in your code that is calling the API with bad arguments.  What does that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out the map element I'm passing to google.maps.Map() didn't exist. So the bug is "it doesn't say so, but it gives an obscure error".

Anyway, hopefully someone can use this solution.